# Remove colmns based on average number of elements in a row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

A bit strange question. Given a sample dataframe:

```
    df = 

   1    1.1     2   2.1     3   3.1     4   4.1     5   5.1

  11     22    33    44    55    66    77    88    99    12
  12     13    14    15   Nan   Nan   Nan   NaN   NaN   NaN
  11     22    33    44    55    66    77   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I want to drop columns containing `NaN` values. But sometimes my `NaN`'s start from 3rd column, so I do not want to drop them. I want to do some approximation or mean. I want to check average length of the rows before `NaN` and drop the rest.

Example:

- 1st row has 10 points
- 2nd row has 4 points
- 3rd row has 6 points

Thus average will be 7. So my data will be:

```
    df = 

   1    1.1     2   2.1     3   3.1     4   

  11     22    33    44    55    66    77   
  12     13    14    15   Nan   Nan   Nan   
  11     22    33    44    55    66    77
```

Ot maybe you can suggest other Data Preparing method

Comment: so you only want to drop the column if a certain fraction of it is `NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the NaN's are going to always be last in rows (eg, you won't have the first column as a NaN, second column a value, then a NaN etc...), you could do something like:

```
df.iloc[:, :int(df.count(axis=1).mean())]
```

Which'll give you:

```
    0   1   2   3     4     5     6
0  11  22  33  44  55.0  66.0  77.0
1  12  13  14  15   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  11  22  33  44  55.0  66.0  77.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have NaN also in first columns as well?

Comment: @Mamed well that depends on how you want to treat it... if the positioning of the first NaN matters, then how would that affect things logic wise? eg: If your DF had all NaNs as the first column, and then all the others populated... how many columns would you expect output?